# How do I add a delegate to event in managed c++ 2010?

Tags: c#, delegates, managed-c++

I've got following code in c#

```
public class Shedluer
{
    public delegate void TaskCompletedDelegate(ulong taskId);
    public static event TaskCompletedDelegate OnTaskCompleted;
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to use it in c++.net:

```
shedluer->OnTaskCompleted+=gcnew Shedluer::TaskCompletedDelegate(OnTaskFinished);
```

where OnTaskFinished is a non-static method declared inside a ref class.

I've seen a bunch of examples for c++.net 2007, but those won't compile in vs 2010.

How do I add a delegate to event in managed c++ 2010?

Comment: `Shedluer`?  Is that supposed to be "scheduler"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the `OnTaskFinished` is in the current class, and that ref class is of type `MyClass`.  In that case, you'd write:

```
shedluer->OnTaskCompleted += gcnew Shedluer::TaskCompletedDelegate(this, &MyClass::OnTaskFinished);
```